# Where do you get Lapis Lazuli on Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I don't know we're you find it and I really need it for enchanting. I know its underground but I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

You can get Lapis Lazuli via breaking blocks of [Lapis Lazuli Ore](https://minecraft.wiki/w/g00/Lapis_Lazuli_Ore?i10c.encReferrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLnJ1Lw%3D%3D&i10c.ua=1&i10c.dv=14).

The easiest way to find it is [mining in the layers 13-16](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Lapis_Lazuli_Ore#Natural_generation). However, my experience shows that you actually find more than you need when simply mining for diamonds (no need to focus Lapis Lazuli).

Comment: This does not answer the question at all. The OP knows its underground. Where underground can you find it? Only dungeons? Between certain levels? Only after obtaining a Notch Apple after slaying the Wither 6 times while flying with your third pair of elytra? Be more specific!

Comment: @KyleRone Fair enough. Added more specifics. :)

Comment: Excellent, changed my vote :)